# Understanding grammar in SableCC

Tags: sablecc

I am going through sableCC for one of my projects and I have few queries about the Grammar file.
1. What is the difference between Helper and Tokens?
2. What should go in helper and Token?
3. And most importantly what is  Productions?

Answer (score 0):

you can  see the thesis [here](http://sablecc.sourceforge.net/downloads/thesis.pdf)

**Token** :  lexical defnitions for numbers, arithmetic op-
erators, parentheses and blanks etc.

**helper** : is a character set or a regular expression
denoted by an identifer.

**Productions** : is a grammar that you define for identify.